# Trying to pick a random point on sphere end up picking from a lune

Tags: probability-distributions, analytic-geometry, mathematica, spherical-geometry

I was inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44689/how-to-find-a-random-axis-or-unit-vector-in-3d) to play around a little bit (its a weekend). I was pretty confident of my derivation and thought it might be nice to supplement it with a pretty picture. However, instead of picking random points from the entire sphere the result I get are a bunch of random points from two opposite [lunes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lune_%28mathematics%29#Spherical_geometry). I've been scratching my head for an hour, and the only suspicion is that the distributions I have derived must be wrong (i.e not the code, I think). I am posting here what I would have hoped to be an answer.

If $\Omega$ is the solid angle, then the probability that a point lies in an infinitesimal cone is $$p(\Omega)d\Omega$$ On normalizing, we get $$\displaystyle \int_{\mbox{unit sphere}} p(\Omega)d\Omega = 1$$ $$p(\Omega) = \frac{1}{4\pi}$$

We can also write $$p(\Omega)d\Omega= p(\theta,\phi) d\theta d\phi$$ Where $\theta$ is the polar angle and $\phi$ is the azimuthal angle. Using $\displaystyle d\Omega = \sin \theta d\theta d\phi$ we get $$p(\theta,\phi) = \frac{\sin\theta}{4\pi}$$

So $$p(\theta) = \int_0^{2\pi}p(\theta,\phi)d\phi = \frac{\sin \theta}{2}$$ $$p(\phi) = \int_0^\pi p(\theta,\phi)\sin\theta d\theta = \frac{1}{2\pi}$$.

To implement this we choose two random variables $u,v$ which are uniform on the interval $(0,1)$ $$\theta = \sin^{-1}(2u)$$
$$\phi = 2\pi v$$

For programming ease I map these points into the cartesian system with the standard transformations.

[image: Lune]

Mathematica Code:

```
theta := ArcSin[2*RandomReal[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]]];
phi := 2 Pi RandomReal[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]];
plotPts = Table[{phi, theta}, {5000}];
cartesian[{theta_, phi_}] := {Sin[theta]*Cos[phi], 
   Sin[theta]*Sin[phi], Cos[theta]};
cPts = cartesian /@ plotPts;
points = Graphics3D[Point /@ cPts];
Show[points]
```

**Mistake:** Random variables should be equated to the CDF (probability) not the PDF. On integrating the PDFs to get the CDFs, the correct random variables are $$\theta = \cos^{-1}(2u-1)$$
$$\phi = 2\pi v$$

And the resulting plot[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that you're just missing a `-1` inside the last `]` of the first line.  When I ran the code, I saw what you saw, but with a whole mess of errors about complex numbers where there shouldn't be any.  Looking over your code, it seemed they must be coming from the `ArcSin[]`, since it looks like you're taking the arcsine of numbers in the interval $[0,2]$ instead of $[-1,1]$.  Hence, my thought about a `-1`, which for me seems to generate a more-covered sphere:

[image: results]

***edit***:  Here's the code with the modification:

```
theta := ArcSin[2*RandomReal[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]]-1 (* Here's the -1 *)];
phi := 2 Pi RandomReal[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]];
plotPts = Table[{phi, theta}, {5000}];
cartesian[{theta_, phi_}] := {Sin[theta]*Cos[phi], 
   Sin[theta]*Sin[phi], Cos[theta]};
cPts = cartesian /@ plotPts;
points = Graphics3D[Point /@ cPts];
Show[points]
```

Comment: Sorry I cant locate it, could you edit my question?

Comment: @yayu: Rather than editing it into your question, I put the edited code into my answer.

Comment: I just realized what I did wrong. It is in the derivation... if I am able to correct it should I leave it as an edit in the question or post it as an answer?

Comment: My mistake was to equate the random variables to the CDF while I equated the PDF's.. that's why I am missing the 1

Comment: @yayu: I'd say post it as an answer, since it's a resolution of the issue you were asking about (and you can mark it as accepted to indicate that your question is answered).

Comment: @Isaac thanks, here's my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44689/how-to-find-a-random-axis-or-unit-vector-in-3d/46234#46234) I've attributed you and made it CW

Comment: @yayu: I actually hadn't thought much about this in terms of the original question.  I suspect, from the looks of the 3d plot, that what you're generating is skewed toward the poles (or some poles), as the original question suggests can happen, rather than being uniform.

Comment: If the method itself is wrong. hmm.. I would have to sleep on this one.

Comment: @yayu: I'm not exactly an expert on this kind of probability—once probability gets to PDFs and CDFs, my knowledge and understanding fades quickly; my answer here was based entirely on debugging the Mathematica code and my suggestion about the uniformity is purely based on how the plot looks.