# Probabilities concerning Uniform Vectors in Unit Sphere

Tags: probability-distributions, spheres

Let $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ be a random variable that has the uniform distribution on the unit sphere $S_2(1)=\{{\bf x}=(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in{\mathbb{R}}^3: ||{\bf x}||=1\}$. As also noted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602036/marginal-distribution-of-uniform-vector-on-sphere),  the marginals are such that
$X_i^2\sim Beta(\frac{1}{2},1). $
Further analysis shows that $X_1^2+X_2^2 \sim Beta(1,\frac{1}{2}).$
Thus, we can easily find the probability $Pr(x_1^2+x_2^2<\alpha)$ using the beta distribution. This probability is equal $I(1,\frac{1}{2};\alpha)$ ([the regularized incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) with parameters 1, 1/2) My question concerns how to find the joint density for $X_1^2$ and $X_1^2+X_2^2.$  As far as I understand, these random variables are not independent (right?), so it is not straightforward to find the joint density. I.e. how to compute $Pr(x_1^2<\alpha,\ \ x_1^2+x_2^2<\beta).$

Also, the joint distribution of $(x_1,x_2)$ has density
$$\frac{\Gamma(3/2)}{\Gamma(1/2)\pi}\Big(1 - x_1^2 - x_2^2\Big)^{-1/2}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\Big(1 - x_1^2 - x_2^2\Big)^{-1/2},$$
see *[example 3.1.3] of K. T. Fang, s. Kotz and Kai-Wang Ng, Multivariate and related distributions.*

First I was thinking somehow to compute this probability using the conditional probability for $X_1^2|X_1^2+X_2^2.$  I made some experiments and found that the histogram for $Pr(X_1^2<1/3|X_1^2+X_2^2<2/3)$ is the following

[image]

Another way is to compute the suitable double integrals (since this probability translates to an area section of a spherical cap) which is tedious. Although is doable and I managed for instance to prove that
$Pr(X_1^2<1/3,\ X_1^2+X_2^2<2/3)=1/3.$  Also, this approach, if we let the dimension of the sphere $n$ to become larger does not seem good. So I am looking for an apporach using only properties of distributions.