# Distribution of squared coordinate of points on $n$-sphere?

Tags: probability, geometry, probability-distributions, euclidean-geometry

Suppose $\mathbf{x}$ is uniformly sampled from the surface of [n-sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere). What is the distribution of $x_1^2$?

This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3019736/998) shows that $x_1$ is distributed as shifted Beta so I can plug it into Mathematica to get  distribution of $x_1^2$ for some specific $n$, wondering if there's an elegant way to derive the formulas below:

$$\begin{matrix}
n=1&\frac{1}{\pi  \sqrt{((1-x) x)}}\\
n=2& \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}\\
n=3& \ldots\\
n=4&\frac{3 (1-x)}{4 \sqrt{x}}\\
n=5&\ldots\\
n=6&\frac{15 (x-1)^2}{16 \sqrt{x}}\\
n=7&\ldots\\
n=8&\frac{35 (1-x)^3}{32 \sqrt{x}}
\end{matrix}$$

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-sphere-squared.nb)

Answer (score 1):

As shown in different [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/286688/217)

$$x_1^2\sim \text{Beta}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{n}{2}\right)$$