# Expected value of randomly distributed projection

Tags: probability, problem-solving

**Problem:** Find the mathematical expectation of the area of the projection of a cube with edge of length 1 onto a plane with an isotropically distributed random direction of projection.

**Source:**
[Arnold's Trivium.](http://hans.math.upenn.edu/Arnold/Arnold-Trivium-1991.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The area of the projection is the area that you see when looking at the cube. You see three faces, and the area under which a face appears is its actual area, $1$, times the absolute value of one of the coordinates of the uniformly random unit direction vector. Those coordinates are uniformly distributed over $[-1,1]$ (see [Generate a random direction within a cone](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56784/generate-a-random-direction-within-a-cone/205589#205589)), so the mean absolute value is $1/2$, so by linearity of expectation the expected projected area is $3/2$.

Comment: @Potato: The area under which a face appears is its actual area times the cosine of the angle between its normal and the viewing direction. We can consider the cube fixed and axis-parallel and the viewing direction uniformly random; then the normals are the canonical basis vectors and the cosines are the coordinates of the viewing direction.

Comment: If I'm following you, this would work only in three dimensions, not in two or $\ge$ four.

Comment: @Michael: You're following me :-) In two dimensions, the answer is twice the average value $2/\pi$ of the absolute value of the cosine, $4/\pi\approx1.27$.