# Random Rotation of Points using Householder matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, rotations, random-matrices

I have $N$ points in $D$ dimensions, were $D$ is big, for sure more than $100$. $N$ is also big.

The goal is to produce an algorithm in my code, that will take as input this dataset and will give another one (in a different matrix), that will be randomly rotated.

I have used [Euler rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_rotation_theorem), but the time complexity of it is $O(N\cdot D\cdot D)$.

Chanop and Hartley note in their paper "Optimised KD-trees for fast image descriptor matching", that:

[image]

but searching the internet didn't help me much, so I literally don't know how to perform this task. I am not asking for code, but for guidance, for what I should do to achieve my goal.

A relevant -maybe- question is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442418/random-generation-of-rotation-matrices) in this site.

Comment: What's the question?  Do you know how to multiply a Householder matrix and a vector in $O(d)$ time?  That I can do.  The second part I cannot do, because I don't know what a tree is.

Comment: Also, how do you use Euler rotations if $D \ne 3$?

Comment: Multiplying by householder matrices does reflection not rotation. You could try Givens rotations.

Comment: I used the generalizations described in the link. Yes that was the case, but after daw's comment, everything got cleared up, tnx!